# Is there any secure storage or secure local db for react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need a secure storage, or local db, or a best encryption library for react-native.

Because I want to store some keys, password inside my app.
It should be store in a secure place, here already `AsyncStorage` is exists, but it is not secure to save keys or ids.

Comment: If you are using Expo you can use `SecureStore` from Expo

Comment: Secured against whom or what?

Comment: I am not using expo I am using react-native alone

Answer (score 1):

Firebase work's great with React Native and you can set your own security rules.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules

Comment: I need to store some keys and Ids on client phone

Answer (score 1):

You can use mongodb Atlas for deployement as well as local

https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas